# What is the difference between my.cnf vs mysql.cnf?

Tags: mysql

In /etc/mysql/ I see two config files: my.cnf and mysql.cnf

Both have almost identical contents. One of them has been recently updated via apt-get. Looks like one of them is obsolete.

Can somebody explain what's the difference between these two and if I can delete one of them?

Using Ubuntu 16.10 and Mysql 5.7.8 here.

Answer (score 19):

I have the same question.

I will assume you meant `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` because I actually have a lot of MySQL configuration files.

I tested and both are required - MySQL will not start up unless they are both present, even though they contain the same content.

```
# Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

From what I understand, `mysql.cnf` are the Ubuntu specific MySQL settings and `my.cnf` are the MySQL default settings.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) contains a table describing what the various config files are supposed to be used for, but it doesn't mention mysql.cnf.

- `/etc/my.cnf` Global options
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` Global options
- `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf` Global options
- `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf` Server-specific options (server only)
- `defaults-extra-file` The file specified with --defaults-extra-file, if any
- `~/.my.cnf`  User-specific options
- `~/.mylogin.cnf` User-specific login path options (clients only)

And as you can see by the contents of these two config file from [this blog](http://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-16-04-default-mysql-5-7-configuration/) my theory seems to be correct.

On my system, I actually have quite a few other configuration files which correspond to the various sections of the MySQL, so you can edit those instead of using the various sections.

**[mysqld]**

These properties are for the MySQL Server, and you can use this file: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

**[mysql]**

These properties are for the MySQL Client (command line), and you can use this file: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

**[mysqld_safe]**

These properties are for MySQL when you start it up in safe mode using [mysql_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html) and can be found in this file: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf`

Answer (score 16):

tl;dr They are the same file.

In Ubuntu 16.04 `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` which by default is a symlink to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

Seems like a lot of symlinks, but they wanted MySQL to read from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and also use the alternatives mechanism.

Comment: This answer helped me see what was going on in Proxysql/Percona Cluster and why my replica nodes were not reading from /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf.  For some reason after updating the replica nodes via Cluster Control they were no longer symlinked however the master node still was.