# Setting new value to MySQL Global variable in the file 'mysql.cnf' gives error 'unkown variable' while trying to log in

Tags: mysql, configuration, permissions, global-variables, privileges

For me the Global Variable is -

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/mysql_files/         |
+---------------------------+
```

Now I want to change it's value. I do -

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

and below `[mysql]` put the value -

```
secure_file_priv = /mysql-files/
```

Then I create the directory `mysql-files`

```
sudo mkdir /mysql-files
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql  /mysql-files/
```

Then I restart the server -

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Now when I try to login I get the following error -

```
mysql -u admin -p
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'secure_file_priv=/mysql-files/'.
```

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: In my.ini you must use the syntax which is used in command line. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv Hence `secure-file-priv = "/mysql-files/"`

Comment: @Akina thank you for your help but still the error persists

Comment: This is server setting, and it must be placed into `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have I have two files - `my.cnf` and `my.cnf`, both including sym link to the directories - `conf.d` and `mysql.conf.d`, in both the directories there is a file `mysql.cnf` and the both the files have `[mysql]`, no file with `[mysqld]` is present

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html#option-file-order

Comment: Thank you for your help but the document you provided is for windows, I am using Ubuntu 21.10, here the installation is somewhat different

Comment: Please read the whole article, not upper 2 lines only.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now, this stackoverflow post was very useful in proper understanding of the mysql installation in Ubuntu - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080687/what-is-the-difference-between-my-cnf-vs-mysql-cnf